# jquery DOM object custom variable atribute inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'karta'+i,    
    znak: player1 
}).appendTo('#igrac1');
```

**znak:player1** one is the way that i tried to make custom atribute inside that object, but its wrong. So is it possible to have custom atribute inside jquery object ?

Comment: i edited my post, check it out now.

Comment: @Игор Рајачић, still makes no sense.

Comment: is it possible to have variables linked to the object that is created by jQuery..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, when using jQuery, it's much safer to use `.data()` to store custom data on an element.  You can do that compactly in your example like this:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {id: 'karta'+i,}).data("znak", player1).appendTo('#igrac1');
```

And, then when you want to reference the znak data, you get it with this:

```
var curPlayer = jQuery("#karta1").data("znak");
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fqaKg/

If you want to set multiple data items on an object, you can do it either with multiple .data() calls or by passing an object to .data():

```
jQuery("#karta1").data("player", "Bob").data("age", 13);
```

or

```
jQuery("#karta1").data({player: "Bob", age: 13});
```

And, those can then be retrieved as:

```
var player = jQuery("#karta1").data("player");
var age = jQuery("#karta1").data("age");
```

Comment: i dont think it works that way you described it. can you provide http://jsfiddle.net example.. how to store data in jquery object, and then read that custom information that you stored in that object using simple alert function.

Comment: @ИгорРајачић - Works fine here in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fqaKg/.

Comment: yea it works, it was mine mistake, i may integrate this as a solution for my project, i have one more question how much variables are possible to store in one data function for example .data("znak","test") works znak is variable test is the value of tha var.. but how to store multiple variables in one data function? thanks in advance mate

Comment: Perhaps you should read [the jQuery `.data()` doc page](http://api.jquery.com/data/).  You can have as many different keys with the `.data()` function as you want.  You just call `.data()` multiple times for each key you want to set.  And there is no limit on the size of the data (other than whatever limitations javascript has).  Internally, jQuery is just storing the data as key/value pairs on a javascript object.

Comment: According to my response above: `jQuery.data(igracDiv, "test",{name:"Joe", age:12});`. You now have name and age stored in igracDiv.

Comment: ok fair enough, thank you kindly for you patience and knowledge, this was most helpful to me, i was the closest answer that i was searching for... thanks once again!

Comment: @phemios yea i saw your example as well, and i understod it, it also solves that multiple var problem, its well explained theere. but unfortunately i can give onlye one solution to the question :( thank all guys who wanted to help.

Comment: @ИгорРајачић - though you can only assign one checkmark, you can upvote (click on the up arrow) for all answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [`jQuery.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function, maybe you can use it in your case. Here is a fiddle with an example i've just made: http://jsfiddle.net/dRtqQ/

Here is the html:

```
<div id="igrac1"></div>
```

Here is the Js:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'karta',    
    znak: 'hey'
}).appendTo('#igrac1');

var igracDiv= $("karta");

// store the information
jQuery.data(igracDiv, "test",{name:"Joe", age:12});

//then to read it (or put it in another variable)
alert(jQuery.data(igracDiv, "test").name);
```

Comment: this is the alternative way to do the same thing, and in some cases its maybe even better to use it this way, so i have gave you only reputation + because i cant tick 2 answers for solution, but im sure it will be very helpful to the other users as well. thank you @phemios

Comment: @Игор No prob, my pleasure. =]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, you need to use `attr`:

http://jsfiddle.net/HGz7D/

```
var newDiv = jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'karta'
}).attr(znak,player1)
```

or you could do this:

```
var details = {
    id: 'karta'
};

details[znak] = player1;

var newDiv = jQuery('<div/>', details).appendTo('body');
```

But as stated in the other question, `data` is usually a better idea than custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting an attribute `znak` to the value of `player1`.  In other words the element would look like this

```
<div id="kart1" znak="<!-- value of player` -->"></div>
```

You might be looking for `$.data` to store a value for the element.